# Is there a way to raise the maximum number of indexes on Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, indexing

I am using Firebase for a couple of while now. Luckily I never came across index limitations. Till now.

We are offering several filter opportunities inside our App which lead to a high amount of indexes inside our firestore database.

As this App is currently at the beginning I am asking myself how future functionalities can be implemented, if the index limitations already hit us right now.

**Is there any way of increasing the index amount?**

Answer (score 1):

If a limit could be increased, then it wouldn't really be a limit, would it?  It would be a configuration.  Firestore's [limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) cannot be configured by the developer.

If you have any chance at all of changing the limit, it would be by [contacting Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) and explaining why you should be able to exceed the limit.

Since the limit is per-database, you can always simply set up another project with another Firestore database, and add more collections into that other database, giving you a whole new set of 200 indexes to work with.  You can work with multiple projects in your app by initializing the SDK multiple times, once for each project.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Sure it wouldn't be a limit if a developer can increase it by himself, but I don't really understand the limitation in the first place.

Is this a common workaround to setup multiple databases and connect them with each other just to get another 200 indexes?

Comment: The limits are set up to support the scalability and reliability of the system for the expected use cases.  If you need to exceed the limits, then your use case might not be appropriately solved by Firestore.  Not all databases are good for all cases.  Look at other databases, consider their capabilities and limits as well, and figure out what's best.